# Is it possible to run apt-get in centos , if yes how?

Tags: centos, apt, rpm

For some reasons I have to use `apt-get` in CentOS. After some effort I noticed RPMForge/RepoForge (which is needed to install `apt-get`) is dead project.

Please refer to [this](https://github.com/repoforge/rpms/issues/375) page. however is it possible to run `apt-get` in CentOS or not, if yes, how?

Comment: What reasons? Why the complication of a foreign package system instead of using the native RPM?

Comment: I'm trying to install Mirantis Openstack, building bootstrap fails because it needs to run apt-get update.

Comment: If you want to install OpenStack on CentOS, you should use RDO, not Mirantis OpenStack.

Comment: Im following this link (https://docs.mirantis.com/openstack/fuel/fuel-9.1/quickstart-guide/qs-install-fuel.html) installation guide, in this tutorial the prepared package installs centos

Comment: The Supported O/S list at [Mirantis Documentation](https://docs.mirantis.com/openstack/fuel/fuel-9.1/quickstart-guide/qs-supported-os.html) doesn't list CentOS, and the last version of Fedora listed is 19. The documentation could be out of date, but it is certainly a flag.

Comment: If you see original document which exactly openstack community publish it, didnt mentioned installing any OS, Im install the prepared Iso file which is available here(https://www.mirantis.com/software/openstack/download/)

Comment: `alias apt-get=yum`. There you go. `apt-get install` shall work :)

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot.

Well, you can. You can build it from source or install it using alien. But it will not work. You will not have the correct repositories and you cannot really use `deb` packages on CentOS. You can spend days on it and then you will wonder why the OpenStack installation does not work.

You should really use OpenStack which list CentOS as supported platform. https://www.rdoproject.org/ is really good choice.

Comment: whats the diffrence of RDO and RedHat openstack?

Comment: I think Redhat openstack isnt free. isnt it?

Comment: RDO is free of charge, but self supported (similar as CentOS), Red Hat OpenStack is paid and supported (similar as Red Hat Enterprise Linux)